# In node.js, how to evaluate formulas in excel that contains reference to cells from another sheets in same workbook?

Tags: node.js, excel, npm

I have an excel sheet that contain multiple formulas. Formulas refer to cells from other sheets in same workbook.Is there any npm package that can evaluate formulas having references of cells from other sheets?

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to do the same thing right now.

My attempt includes:

- [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) - to read values and functions from the file
- [hot-formula-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-formula-parser) - to evaluate functions

  - This library will fire an event each time it tries to evaluate a cell reference.
  - See [callcellvalue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-formula-parser#callcellvalue-cellcoord-done) documentation for more information
  - Also see [callrangevalue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-formula-parser#callrangevalue-startcellcoord-endcellcoord-done) documentation for more when range is required

This should suffice to implement the solution.
Let me know how it works and share your work :)
I will also share mine if I get it working.

## Update

So turns out the library [hot-formula-parser] does not officially support cross sheet references. See more info at [this ticket](https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser/issues/30)

However, I opened a PR for them to support it. Currently available at [my fork](https://github.com/GuyMograbi/formula-parser/tree/add-cross-sheet-support)

I am also working on a library that will enable you to point to a cell, and it will evaluate it. So even if it points to other cells which are formulas, it will recursively evaluate them. Let me know if it is of any interest to you.

## Another Small Update

I was able to finish a POC that evaluates thousands of formulas along the way using the stack mentioned above and my PR.

I required some more patches along the way, but most of them can be worked-around if you can modify the excel file (for example, the name of the tab could not have spaces).

Comment: can you provide a snippet on how you were able to evaluate thousands of formula pointing to a formula cell